# Converting an analog Butterworth filter into a discrete filter

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, active-filter, digital-filter

Here again to ask about another question. This time asking how to convert an analog transfer function to a discrete transfer function using standard continuous to discrete methods.

The application that I am trying to achieve is to have an audio source fed into an arduino A/D then have the output of the A/D fed into the plant then take the output from the plant into a D/A and capture that.

Recap: Audio Signal -> A/D -> Digital Filter -> D/A -> Output

The analog transfer function: a Low Pass Filter Fc = 20kHz

$$H(s) = \frac{1}{6.416\cdot10^{-11}s^2+1.133\cdot10^{-5}s+1}$$

Upon researching about this topic I learned that each continuous to discrete methods are used in different applications, for instance.

- Tustin: Used to preserve the frequency response from the continuous function.
- Zoh: Used to preserve the step response from continuous
- Matched: Preserve the pole and zero locations of the continuous function

etc..

Where I am getting confused is that I believe you should be using the 'ZoH' transform whenever you are converting from continuous to discrete due to the fact you will be adding the dynamics of the D/A. Now, I have read/watched online that you have to be careful doing a 'ZoH' transform, as if you already have a D/A in the system you might be adding the dynamics of a D/A twice. Wouldn't you always have a D/A in the system when doing things like this though?

Guess what I am asking is when is it and is not appreciate to use ZoH, Tustin, and the other methods then and how do I appropriately transfer that continuous function to a discrete function properly.

Comment: What is the purpose of that filter? Also, one of the eigenvalues is slightly negative and the other one is \$-2 \cdot 10^{15}\$, pretty sure that that will end up causing problems for the digital implementation.

Comment: The purpose of this filter is for me to try to convert an analog filter to a discrete filter, and its a LPF.

Comment: That filter does not have a cut-off frequency of 20 kHz, please double check your calculations. And also, if you intend on putting that in a microcontroller, you should either find one with a FPU/DSP or use some sort of integer coefficient filter and optimize it a lot.

Comment: @jDAQ typo in my transfer function, try it again.

Comment: What, hold on. You sure thats not rad/s?

Comment: I am getting 20kHZ now. or 1.25e05 rad/s

Comment: Are you sampling at about 45k to make this work?

Comment: The freq is correct, I misread the units

Comment: @ScottSeidman thats the idea, I was going to get to that part once I figure out how to properly transform this

Comment: One EXTREMELY important issue. ADC anti aliasing filters cannot be implemented digitally after sampling. Just keep that in mind. By the time you sample it is too late to deal with aliasing. If this is not an anti-aliasing filter than it is all good.

Comment: Also, the ATMEGA328p ADC has only 15kSPS, so you won't attain the 45kSPS suggested by @ScottSeidman with an Arduino Uno (as in your other post regarding this).

Comment: @jDAQ Thats going to have to come after as I dont know how to determine if a microcontroller is suitable as I see the ATMEGA328p has a 16mHZ clock onboard. I would assume it would be okay

Comment: Sample rate will be central to your transform to digital.

Comment: Yeah understood, but for theoretical purposes how would one transform this. Assuming I have a capable MCU to handle this

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform is where I would start

Comment: But, once you have the signal in the digital domain, there's really not much worth to building a Butterworth filter when you can build any filter you want.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Fair. Are you saying there's better filters to be built then? Also thank you for the link. I really wanted to know why are you choosing the Tustin method over the other methods?

Comment: Bilinear transform is pretty tried and true, and the frequency warp is well understood.  Unless you can provide guidelines for how you're trying to optimize, we can discuss advantages and disadvantages of any method and never get close to an answer.  As for better filters, yes, in the digital domain it is dirt simple to approximate a boxcar in the frequency domain with a windowed sinc function (Hanning or Hamming window).  The wider your filter, the closer to ideal it will be.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I see what you mean. I guess I was hopping to learn which method to use over the others and learn about the topology of implementing the D/A and A/D in the block diagram to get more of a sense of it.